# Why i can not fetch data from controller from ajax function?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm beginner in asp.net mvc ,and want to fetch simple json from controller to ajax variable,for that purpose in view page write this ajax function:

```
<script>
    var OutPut;
    OutPut = "behzad";
    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("callService", "myPassword")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: { 'id': 2 },
            success: function (color) {
                OutPut= color;

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });
        alert("I think is ok!"+":"+OutPut);

    }
</script>
```

and this controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult callService(int id)
        {
            string JSON = "behzad";
            return Json(JSON,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

that ajax function call with this html code in view page:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="CallService()">Success</button>
```

but this line in ajax function:

```
alert("I think is ok!"+":"+OutPut);
```

Output is undefined,what happen?is controller return null?or why i get undefined alert?thanks.

Comment: ajax is async and your `alert(..)` will be called before your ajax call returns a value. In the code you have shown, the output will be "behzad" (not undefined) because you have declared it globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the AJAX call is asynchronous, you should place the alert **inside** the success callback:

```
<script>
    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("callService", "myPassword")',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { 'id': 2 },
            success: function (color) {
                alert("I think is ok!" + ":" + color);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error occurred');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```